# Kotlin Property Initialization (Like swift using closures)

Tags: swift, kotlin

I recently started looking into Kotlin after wanting to expand my mobile development from just iOS to Android as well, as was trying to find something similar to how swift allows you to use closures to initialize properties.

```
//Swift init using closure
let myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    // Init Code

    return label
}()
```

So far I haven't been able to find this with some google searches, and was wondering if this were possible or not. Is this possible? Or is there even some workaround for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`apply()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html):

```
val myLabel : UILabel().apply {
    // in this block, `this` is the UILabel being initialized 
    color = "blue"
    text = "hello"
}
```